# php parse html data from specific positions

Tags: php

I have a lot of these in my html document:

```
<div class="thumb-under">
    <p class="title">
        <a href="1A" title="2A">text</a>
    </p>
    <p class="metadata">
        <span class="bg">
            <span class="first">3A
            </span>
            <a href="4A">
                <span class="name">5A
                </span></a>
            <span>
                <span class="spring"> - 
                </span> 6A
                <span class="spring">something
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="spring"> - 
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

so I need to extract data from positions 1A, 2A, 3A, 4A, 5A, 6A

I tried this but something I am doing wrong:

```
$matches = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tr) {
    if ( ! $tr->hasAttribute('class')) {
       continue;
    }

    $class = explode(' ', $tr->getAttribute('class'));


    if (in_array('title', $class)) {
       $matches[] = $tr->getElementsByTagName('a');
    }
  

}
print_r($matches);
```

I am totally lost...

Comment: This gives me `Array ( [0] => DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 1 ) )` as result. So what is “wrong” with that, in your opinion? It obviously added a DOM element list to your array … sounds like you just neglected to do anything further with it at this point?

Comment: yes, I thought $matches should return content of "a" but instead of it it returns [length] => 1 what I do not know, what it is.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. Do you want to extract text data from <a href="1A" title="2A">

Comment: yes, exactly, this is what I would like to get extracted

Comment: _“I thought $matches should return content of "a" but instead of it it returns [length] => 1 what I do not know, what it is.”_ - `getElementsByTagName` does not return a single node, it returns a _list_ of nodes. Always, even if there is only one matching node. So you need to proceed by getting at the element(s) on that list - if you expect there to be only one, you can use `[0]`, if there could be more, you might want to loop over them instead.

Comment: _“I thought $matches should return content of "a" but instead of it it returns [length] => 1 what I do not know, what it is.”_ - `getElementsByTagName` does not return a single node, it returns a _list_ of nodes. Always, even if there is only one matching node. So you need to proceed by getting at the element(s) on that list - if you expect there to be only one, you can use `[0]`, if there could be more, you might want to loop over them instead.

Comment: @CBroe nice, now I understand and it works. I changed my code. For now I stuck on getting values A1-A6 in one foreach cycle :))) But I am making progress. Thanks!